# VBScript Regular Expressions to find pattern of numbers only

Tags: vbscript

I need to know how to use vbscript regular expressions to find any part of the text that has 5 numbers together.

For example:

NumberNumberNumberNumberNumber

or

12345

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern "\d{5}" to specify five digits. The match collection from .Execute will hold your interesting parts. In code:

```
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Global = True
>> r.Pattern = "\d{5}"
>> s = "12345a1234b1234554321c123456d"
>> For Each m In r.Execute(s)
>>     WScript.Echo m.Value
>> Next
>>
12345
12345
54321
12345
```