# VBScript remove letters from string

Tags: vbscript

can u write me how to take string and remove all letter and signs and leave only 7 digit? 
example: 
if I got abc1234567-d  or a12c3f-45kj6%7ud-

then return 1234567 
Thanks

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far and then we can give out inputs. Thats the way to learn brother.

Comment: Please do not [broadcast](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/fb.ashx?m=108687) your question across the Internet. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript Regular Expressions to find pattern of numbers only](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23544233/692942)

Comment: It shouldn't surprise people, that since SOs inception these types of questions have been asked, just search either using SO Search or Google. It takes seconds...

Answer (score 0):

This removes all but `0-9`, `.`, and `,` as they are valid parts of numbers.

This is known as *regular expressions*. See VBScript's Help.

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[^0-9\.,]"
re.Global = True
re.IgnoreCase = True
Sortkey = re.Replace(Sortkey, "")
```

Comment: The OP wants to keep just digits, so `\D` or `\D+` would be a more appropriate expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function ExtractNumber(Source as string) as string
    dim result as string = string.empty
    for each c as char in Source
        if isnumeric(c) then result &= c
    next
    return result
end function
```

Comment: That seems to be VB.net, not VBScript.